# Is my result correct using resolution method?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

On using the resolution method for this formula:

$ \forall x \forall z \big( \neg p ( x ) \lor r ( z ) \big) , \forall x \big( r ( x ) \rightarrow p ( x ) \big) \models \forall x p ( x ) \lor \forall x q ( x ) $.

I resulted that: $\text {Domain}: \{ 1 \}$, $ p ( 1 ) : \text {False}$, $ q ( 1 ) : \text {False}$, $ r ( 1 ) : \text {True}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, it is not....

Comment: @Mauro. Please what should it be?

Comment: See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique): "All sentences in the knowledge base and the negation of the sentence to be proved (the conjecture) are conjunctively connected. The resulting sentence is transformed into a conjunctive normal form."

Comment: What have you tried ? to prove it or to find a counter-example ? To prove it, a single example will not suffice.

Comment: As a counter-example, it is wrong:  p(1): false and r(1) true means that : r(1) → p(1) is false and thus the premise  ∀x(r(x) → p(x)) is false.

Comment: @Mauro. Thanks alot!